# Why I'm getting GridViewUpdateEventArgs#NewValues and GridViewUpdateEventArgs#OldValues empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I'm binding GridView like -

```
namespace grid_edit
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data source=HP_OWNER\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=demo;Integrated security=true";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from demo", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            mySqlAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
            DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataSource = myDataTable;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            Session["mytable"] = myDataTable;


        }
        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }       

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            String updatedItem = e.NewValues[0].ToString();
            String anotherUpdatedItem = e.NewValues[1].ToString();

        }

    }
}
```

and having Mark up like following -

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
            BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" 
            CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black"            
        style="top: 63px; left: 309px; position: absolute; height: 183px; width: 312px; margin-top: 25px;" 
        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"        
        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" >
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

        </asp:GridView>
```

Now I would like to update the rows from the grid view but in the update event `GridViewUpdateEventArgs` I'm getting NewValues  and OldValues empty. 
How can I get the the updated values to store in the DB ? Am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change the code as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data source=(local);Database=northwind;Integrated security=true";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Categories", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        mySqlAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
        DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataSource = myDataTable;
    if(!IsPostBack)  /// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        GridView1.DataBind();
        Session["mytable"] = myDataTable;

    }
```

It works fine here for .NET Framework 4.

Since you are using .NET Framework 3.0, this code does not work.  I have looked at the GridView's HandleUpdate method and found out that these collections (e.NewValues and e.OldValues) are only populated when the Gridview is bound to a DataSourceControl through DataSourceID property...  A possible solution is to use the [ExtractValuesFromCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.extractvaluesfromcell.aspx) method:

```
    cell = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1] as DataControlFieldCell;
    GridView1.Columns[1].ExtractValuesFromCell(
        e.NewValues,
        cell,
        DataControlRowState.Edit,
        true);
```

NOTE: the Page_Load method should have the code as I suggested, i.e. the DataBind should called only once.

Comment: If so, something else affects this.  you may send me your aspx and c# markup.  I will take a look.

Comment: here is the link - https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6ZcRaSNJ6F-Y2MxY2VhMWYtOTM5Yy00NTk1LWEyYzQtYzg3NjBmNmVjMTk2&hl=en_US

Comment: sorry, here is the new link- https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6ZcRaSNJ6F-YjY4MzU3OTAtNmU5YS00YTE5LTk3ODctYjIyNzJmZDFiMzc2&hl=en_US

Comment: now GridView1.Columns[1]  throws OutOfRangeException and I'm using .Net 3.5

Comment: sorry, I forgot tell that you should explicitly create columns in the GridView.  Otherwise, this code won't work

Comment: @platon let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1306/discussion-between-shubhangi-motling-and-platon)

Comment: Try e.Keys instead GridView1.Columns[1].ExtractValuesFromCell(e.Keys,cell, DataControlRowState.Edit,true);